# Why dose it keep telling me There is a loop error?

Tags: reactjs

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

im doing a Google search bar Clone and making the ReactJS context API and got to this spot where i stopped and cant go more cz didnt know how to fix it.
I don't see the infinite loop in my code, can anyone help?

```
function Search({hideButtons = false}) {
const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const history = useHistory();


const search = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push('/search');
};

dispatch({
    type: actionTypes.SET_SEARCH_TERM,    //<<<<<<<< Here where is tell me got the error
    term: input
});


return (
    <form className='search'>
        <div className='search__input'>
            <SearchIcon className='search__inputIcon' />
            <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
            <MicIcon />
        </div>

        {!hideButtons ? (
            <div className='search__buttons'>
                <Button type='submit' onClick={search} variant='outlined'>Google Search</Button>
                <Button variant='outlined'>I'm Feeling Lucky</Button>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div className='search__buttons'>
                <Button className='search__hideButtons' type='submit' onClick={search} variant='outlined'>Google Search</Button>
                <Button className='search__hideButtons' variant='outlined'>I'm Feeling Lucky</Button>
            </div>
        )}

    </form>
)
```

Comment: this is the other Component : `const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case actionTypes.SET_SEARCH_TERM:
            return{
                ...state,
                term: action.term
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
`

Comment: Please use the **edit** option to add the ^above code to your question

Answer (score 0):

I think `dispatch` is the problem here it should be called only when the input value has changed using `useEffect` hook.
Since it's inside the component it keeps calling every time when the component re-renders.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
       type: actionTypes.SET_SEARCH_TERM, 
       term: input
    });
}, [input]);
```